# Generalized gravitational entropy and entanglement entropy

Tags: gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, entanglement-entropy

What are the differences (if any) between Generalized gravitational entropy ([Lewkowycz-Maldacena](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4926)) and holographic entanglement entropy ([Ryu-Takayanagi](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0603001))?

More specifically, I was wondering following the same procedure in the appendix A of [Lewkowycz-Maldacena paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4926) shouldn't one reproduce the usual correction to EE due to a "heavy operator" (whose dimension is fixed by the mass of the bulk scalar field) in the dual 2D CFT?